# how to call javascript when load jsp page?

Tags: javascript

I have a button which should be disabled when the JSP page loads.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You mean the button should be disabled when the page is loaded? If so, this can be done with CSS only.

Comment: @Artem Barger: Ups, yes I mean HTML. I did so much with CSS recently that it seems the only thing in my mind ;) (and very often, if someone wants to achieve some effect with JavaScript, this *can* be replaced by just using CSS ;) )

Answer (score 1):

If there is no any specific conditions for disabling button, you can use HTML attribute disabled. Like this, instead of dynamically changing it on load.

```
<input type="button" disabled="disabled" value="My button" name="btn1" />
```

Comment: The only value the disabled attribute can have is "disabled", "true" is not a valid value.

Comment: @David Dorward: Incorrect, on w3.org the disabled attribute is listed as a **Boolean**.

Comment: I wouldn't cite w3schools over the W3C... @animuson http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#didx-boolean_attribute `Boolean attributes may legally take a single value: the name of the attribute itself (e.g., selected="selected").`

Comment: @deceze: Thanks for clearing that up, I was looking at an XHTML sheet that only listed the attribute as a Boolean without explanation.